# How do I deploy an arbitrary folder to an Azure App Service as part of a GitLab CI process?

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service, gitlab-ci

I have source code for an Angular 4 app in a GitLab repository. On each commit, a GitLab CI process runs `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: alexsuch/angular-cli

package:
  script:
    - npm install
    - ng build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist
```

This grabs a docker image containing the Angular CLI, installs the required dependencies with `npm install` and then does an `ng build`. The output of the build is the `dist` folder which is published as an artefact.

I would like to deploy this folder to an Azure Web App, but I'm struggling to find a sensible way. Normally I would configure Azure to download the contents of the Git repo and deploy that way, but in the Angular case, it is the transpiled output I would like to get deployed.

I don't think the `dist` folder should be checked into **source** control. Copying files to Dropbox and configuring that as the deployment source seems like a horrible hack. How do I automatically get the contents of the private GitLab artefact into my Azure app on each commit?

Comment: Doesn't your question come down to "how do I deploy an arbitrary folder to an App Service", making the GitLab and Angular parts mostly irrelevant? If so, you should rephrase accordingly to focus on the essential.

Comment: @DavidEbbo - It could come down to that. I imagine there are other solutions though? I wondered if it was possible for Azure to pull the artefacts from GitLab using the Gitlab artefact URL (https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html). The fact it is an Angular application is totally irrelevant. I've remove the tag and updated the title of the question. I will see if I can make the body of the question clearer as well. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: It is possible using msdeploy ARM provider if artifact are zipped and available somewhere Azure can access.